# Radio button rendering in DomPdf

Tags: php, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I'm creating a Pdf from html using DomPdf and the following radio button renders in the Pdf when created on my local server (XAMP on Win7):

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" checked />
```

But when rendered using the online server it produces a question mark, rather than a radio button. The html is exactly the same and the DomPdf class files are exactly the same. The other html elements are fine. Also tried without 'checked' and without the closing tag. Any ideas please?

As requested here is the full code of a simplified test page, with one radio button (it makes no difference having multiple radios).

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" checked />
</body>
</html>

<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();

use Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Exception;

require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("radio.pdf", array('Attachment'=>'0'));
?>
```

Comment: Is it only one radio with that name on the page?

Comment: No, multiple radios grouped by name.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set a different value for name attribute, they should have a common name value, just like you group items, for example:

```html
    <input type="radio" name="group1" />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" />
    
    <!-- You can select any one from each group -->
    
    <input type="radio" name="group2" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" />
```

Comment: No, there are already multiple radios grouped by name, makes no difference. It must be something outside the html causing the issue.

Comment: would be better to know what is wrong if you post all code of the page

Answer (score 0):

It was the font cache lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php. I had uploaded the copy from my local server. Once I uploaded the 'dist' copy the radios and checkbox rendered correctly.